# What's the difference between Object and BasicObject in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

What's the difference between these classes? What's the difference between their purposes?

Comment: The docs answer the first part. BasicObject has less functionality and can be used instead of Object if you'd end up removing a bunch of Object methods anyway.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

[BasicObject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html) was introduced in Ruby 1.9 and it is a parent of [Object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html) (thus `BasicObject` is the parent class of all classes in Ruby).

`BasicObject` has almost no methods on itself:

> ```
> ::new
> #!
> #!=
> #==
> #__id__
> #__send__
> #equal?
> #instance_eval
> #instance_exec
> ```

---

> **BasicObject** can be used for creating object hierarchies independent of
>   Ruby's object hierarchy, proxy objects like the Delegator class, or
>   other uses where namespace pollution from Ruby's methods and classes
>   must be avoided.
>
> BasicObject does not include Kernel (for methods like puts) and
>   BasicObject is outside of the namespace of the standard library so
>   common classes will not be found without a using a full class path.

---

> **Object** mixes in the Kernel module, making the built-in kernel
>   functions globally accessible. Although the instance methods of Object
>   are defined by the Kernel module...

You can use `BasicObject` as a parent of your object in case if you don't need methods of `Object` and you would undefine them otherwise:

```
# when you inherit Object
class Tracer
  instance_methods.each do |m|
    next if [:__id__, :__send__].include? m
    undef_method m
  end

  # some logic
end

# when you inherit BasicObject
class Tracer < BasicObject
  # some logic
end
```