# why does Object.superclass.respond_to? :object_method ?

Tags: ruby

I am confused.
When I define a method in Object
I can call it in Objects **superclass** BasicObject!

Like so:

```
class Object
  def object_method
    "object_method called"
  end
end

Object.superclass.respond_to? :object_method
# => true

Object.superclass.object_method
# => "object_method called"
```

I have expected that **only derived classes** inherit the new method!

P.S.: I come to this question from an exercise on [rubymonk](http://rubymonk.com)

.. implement a method superclasses inside Object ..

where the recursion stop criterion is "affected".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `Object.superclass`, you get an object that describes `BasicObject` class.

This object is an instance of `Class` class that inherits from `Object`. Therefore, it has all the methods that `Object` has, including the one you added.

However, instances of the `BasicObject` class do not have this method:

```
irb(main):122:0> Object.object_method
=> "object_method called"

irb(main):123:0> Object.new.object_method
=> "object_method called"

irb(main):124:0> Object.superclass.object_method  # Same as BasicObject.object_method
=> "object_method called"

irb(main):125:0> Object.superclass.new.object_method  # Same as BasicObject.new.object_method
NoMethodError: undefined method `object_method' for #<BasicObject:0x441743be>
        from (irb):125:in `evaluate'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065:in `eval'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1390:in `loop'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1173:in `catch'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1173:in `catch'
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.0/bin/irb:13:in `(root)'
```

---

Here is more stuff to meditate on:

```
irb(main):129:0> Object
=> Object
irb(main):130:0> Object.class
=> Class
irb(main):131:0> Object.new.class
=> Object
irb(main):132:0> Object.superclass
=> BasicObject
irb(main):133:0> Object.superclass.class
=> Class
irb(main):134:0> Object.superclass.new.class
NoMethodError: undefined method `class' for #<BasicObject:0x1c944d4a>
        from (irb):134:in `evaluate'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065:in `eval'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1390:in `loop'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1173:in `catch'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1173:in `catch'
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.0/bin/irb:13:in `(root)'
```

Have fun!

Comment: There’s also the ever-bizarre `Class.class #=> Class` & `Class.new.class #=> Class`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: What else should `Class.class` be? Also `AlmostAnyClass.new.class # => AlmostAnyClass`...

Comment: @Marc-André It’s not that I think it’s unexpected, it’s more just interesting how meta it is.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see, it is a derived class.

```
#ruby 1.8.7
Object.superclass
# => nil
nil.kind_of? Object
# => true

#ruby 2.0.0
Object.superclass
# => BasicObject 
BasicObject.kind_of? Object
# => true
```

Comment: Ok both is true:
`Object.kind_of? BasicObject`
=> true
and 
`BasicObject.kind_of? Object`
=> true

Comment: @ovhaag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894817/whats-the-difference-between-object-and-basicobject-in-ruby

Comment: It continues to be surprising because 

"You can use BaseObject as a parent of your object in case if you don't need methods of Object"

And then a new method in Object sort of monkeypatches BasichObject

Comment: @ovhaag Considering actual behavior, I think they meant "in case if you don't need *instance methods* of Object".

Comment: @jokester In this case object_method is an instance method of Object

Comment: @ovhaag Yes, and not an instance method of BasicObject. I don't see much inconsistency here.

Comment: @jokester the fog begins to lift. I'll sleep over it now.