# Ruby Objects - Then and Now

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, object, inheritance

I'm reading through [Why's (poignant) Guide to Ruby](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/), and in chapter 5, when he's discussing the ability to analyze class structure by using the `:superclass` method, he has this snippet of `irb` interaction:

```
irb> Class.superclass
  => Module
irb> Kernel.class
  => Module
irb> Module.superclass
  => Object
irb> Object.superclass
  => nil
```

I attempted to recreate this in *my* `irb` and got the following output:

```
irb> Class.superclass
  => Module
irb> Kernel.class
  => Module
irb> Module.superclass
  => Object
irb> Object.superclass
  => BasicObject
irb> BasicObject.superclass
  => nil
```

I know that many languages now follow this paradigm of having virtually everything inherit from a single, parent object.

My question is, when and why did Ruby introduce a `BasicObject` class, which extends to `Object`? Was the `Object` class not ***good*** enough for you?! Sheesh!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894817/whats-the-difference-between-object-and-basicobject-in-ruby

Comment: Right you are. Thank you!